# LoadImage unexpected size LR_DEFAULTSIZE

Tags: visual-c++

If I am reading the documentation correctly then the following call should return a bitmap of dimensions cx,cy. However it does not. Am I doing something wrong?
The IDB_BITMAP1 is 16x16 pixels.

```
HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

::GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);
int cx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
int cy = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
```

results: cx=32, cy=32, bmp.Width=16, bmp.Height=16

Comment: IMAGE_BITMAP is the issue.  A bitmap is not an icon, only an icon is capable of storing images with more than one size.  A bitmap does not have a default size, you get whatever size it was designed to be.

Comment: HICON hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME), IMAGE_ICON, 0,0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

Comment: Well it does appear thet it does indeed work with Icons.
Here the Icon contains a single bitmap of size 16x16
 HICON hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON, 0,0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE);
GetIconInfo(hIcon, &info);
    ::GetObject(info.hbmColor, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);
Result bmp.Width = 32, bmp.Height = 32.

Comment: I think you are right Hans. Although the documentation never states it doesnt work for IMAGE_BITMAP.
I will assume the documentation to be inaccurate unless anyone knows different. Its not a show stopper, but does explain why bitmaps which are being used instead of icons not the correct size when the display zoom level is not set to 100%.

Comment: It does state that: "Uses the width or height specified by the system metric values **for cursors or icons**".